# Can I get decode an EntityFramework Model from a specified migration?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Apparently IMigrationMetadata.Target encodes the state of the EF model.
Can I use this to reconstruct the model for a particular migration?

Comment: +1, we want to avoid running migrations automatically and instead run them when an admin invokes them, so we need to be able to reconstruct a model from whatever the current migration is.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Like where and when would you like to reconstruct the model? What problem would you like to solve?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I was myself curious what exactly those magic resource strings were storing. By [digging into the Entity Framework source](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/32435ee2f8774d62562ec31067a7abca670d083c#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbMigrator.cs) (see the `DbMigrator.GetLastModel()` method), I found out that the `IMigrationMetadata.Target` just stores a base-64 string containing gzipped XML data. To test this, I created a new console application containing a simple code-first model defined as follows:

```
public class ContactContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a migration using the NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
PM> Add-Migration MyMigration
```

Next I added the following code to my application's `Main()` method to decode the value in that string and dump it to the console:

```
var migration = new MyMigration();
var metadata = (IMigrationMetadata)migration;
var compressedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(metadata.Target);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(compressedBytes);
var gzip = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
var reader = new StreamReader(gzip);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

This [outputs an EDMX file](https://gist.github.com/lasandell/5277787)  representing the Entity Data Model associated with my `DbContext` that created the migration. If I write this output to a file with the `.edmx` extension, I'm able to open it with Visual Studio and view it in the Entity Designer.

Then if for some reason I wanted to regenerate the `DbContext` and entity classes that produced the model, I would need only do the following:

1. Add the `.edmx` file to a Visual Studio project.
2. Install the [EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2) if I don't already have it.
3. Add the related T4 templates by selecting `Add -> New Item` from project node context menu.
4. Modify the newly added `.tt` files, replacing `$edmxInputFile$` with the name of my `.edmx` file.
5. Watch as the two templates magically regenerate my code-first types to their respective `.cs` files.

Hope that answers your question! :-D

Comment: Cool. Now i just need to think of an actual application for this :D

Comment: Great stuff @luksan, thanks! For anyone interested I've created a little Gist that can extract the EDMX from the target hash and compress it back again: https://gist.github.com/gligoran/87fe3e8eadf5db97ad03. I use this when I need to change a migration without disturbing the rest of the chain. I extract the EDMX from my change migration, edit the XML and compress it back to get the new target. I then have to do this for every migration that follows the changed one.

Answer (score 5):

I created a small console app to export EDMX from the Model column of the __MigrationHistory table https://github.com/andreydil/EfMigrationModelDecoder
You can choose specific migration using `/migration` parameter, i.e:

```
EfMigrationModelDecoder.Cli.exe "<connectionString here>" /migration:Init
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a PowerShell script to extract the latest migration from a DB to a edmx-file.

https://gist.github.com/otto-gebb/93d021c8fd300646dba0073a77585a94

Answer (score 2):

You can also use SQL...

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml, DECOMPRESS(Model)) FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] WHERE MigrationId = 'NameOfMigration'
```

Comment: I tried it in my MSSQL 2008,It doesn't work.Warning 'DECOMPRESS' doesn't exist. which version sqlserver you use?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 and later.  Sorry...I just haven't seen a SQL 2008 server in quite a whiel.