# Migration Generated that Already Matches Schema

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class something like

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string Bar { get; set; }
    // Other Stuff
}
```

It is now necessary to treat `Bar` like a CHAR(8) so I modified the property to

```
    [StringLength(8)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public virtual string Bar { get; set; }
```

There are many migrations in the project, generally that add new classes or new properties to existing classes. I know I could just generate a new migration that changes the column type, but it seemed a bit convoluted to initially create the column as NVARCHAR(Max) and then change it to CHAR(8). I edited the initial migration, changing

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Foo",
    c => new
        {
            Bar = c.String(),
            // Other stuff
        })
```

to

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Foo",
    c => new
        {
            Bar = c.String(maxLength: 8, fixedLength: true, storeType: "char", unicode: false),
            // Other stuff
        })
```

I then deleted the database and ran a program that used the context, thus re-creating the database.

I set a breakpoint in that initial migration and also at the end of the last migration. As soon as the initial migration completes, the table Foo is created in the newly re-created database with the expected column type CHAR(8). *After* the final migration completes and I attempt to use the context, I get an `AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException`.

I then scripted a migration to see what EF things the differences are, and get

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.Foo", "Bar", c => c.String(maxLength: 8, fixedLength: true, unicode: false));
}

public override void Down()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.Foo", "Bar", c => c.String());
}
```

The Up() migration is doing what was already done when the table was created (and physically matches the schema), while the Down() migration wants to change the column back NVARCHAR(Max), which it never was.

**Question**

Why does EF attempt to perform this seemingly unnecessary migration, and can I alter the column type without first creating the NVARCHAR(Max) and then changing it to CHAR(8) in a new, separate migration?

Comment: Problem is each migration stores the model which it uses to do the compares. Changing Up() code does not affect those stored models. You could comment out the change and do an update-database to sync it back up or you could do a much more complicated altering of the gzipped resx model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709849/can-i-get-decode-an-entityframework-model-from-a-specified-migration

Comment: @SteveGreene: I am deleting and regenerating the database, so the __MigrationHistory table is empty when the process starts. I'm not sure where else the model would be stored.

Comment: It's stored in the migration in your solution. If you expand one of your migrations in VS your will see a .resx file which contains the metadata for the code model used to when the migration was created (gzipped XML). When it is applied to the new database it is stored in the model column of each record. So since your change never made it into that zipped model EF thinks it still needs it.

Comment: Interesting. I had looked at the .resx before in VS and only see DefaultSchema and Target. I do see the encoded model when opening the .resx in a text editor.

Comment: I think your comments adequately answer the question. Feel free to create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501) describes the internals of the migration process. The issue here has to do with the comparison model that is embedded in a resource file for the migration being generated at creation time. If you change the Up() Down() code you can affect the generated script, but not the initial comparison model.

It is not advised to change these models, although this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709849/can-i-get-decode-an-entityframework-model-from-a-specified-migration) shows how you can inspect it. The advised workaround is to create a new migration so the model is inserted into it's resource file. Use the -IgnoreChanges flag to create a blank migration with just a model update. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#option1