# How to retrieve Blob (VarBinary) data as string from SQL Server 2012 using a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to get a blob data from database through a stored procedure I am able to get the data but the problem is the data is for an ASP.NET MVC application where it converts using `ConvertToList`:

```
public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(this DataTable dt)
{
    var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
        {
            var objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (var pro in properties)
            {
                if (columnNames.Contains(pro.Name))
                {
                    if (pro.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                        pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name].ToString().ToInt32(), null);
                    else if (pro.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.Double"))
                        pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name].ToString().ToDouble(), null);
                    else if (pro.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.String"))
                        pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name].ToString(), null);
                    else if (pro.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.Int64"))
                        pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name].ToString().ToInt32(), null);
                    else if (pro.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.Boolean"))
                        pro.SetValue(objT, Convert.ToBoolean(row[pro.Name].ToString()), null);
                    //else if (pro.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"))
                    //    pro.SetValue(objT, Convert.ToByte(row[pro.Name]), null); 
                }
            }
            return objT;
        }).ToList();
}
```

When a `System.Byte[]` data is fetched, it always is set to null; I have tried to convert it using usual Byte to string conversion such as

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```

and

```
string s3 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

This cannot be done since my `return` type is a `var` so I tried to convert using stored procedure while it's selecting like this

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), LME.CoverPageImage, 2)
```

but it's still returning null value after the `ConvertToList` is called!

Is there any way to get it as a string from the database through a stored procedure or to convert it using C# ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Have you checked the value in the table? Maybe it is null in the database.

Comment: @Alex No I have checked it for the Id am calling it does have value in that column

Comment: I can't see a problem.  Please try debugging tell us at what stage a non-NULL value becomes NULL.

Comment: The problem is my ```ConvertToList``` function somehow sets the value to null if the datatype is ```System. Byte``` So here is how I overcome the situation Using this method link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664937/retrieve-varbinary-value-as-base64-in-mssql retrived the data  as a string and later the image src attribute dynamically set using a javascript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This cannot be done since my return type is a var

No.  `var` is not at type.

run

```
var data = row[pro.Name];
var typeName = data.GetType().Name;
```

to see the runtime type of the DataTable column.  I think you'll find that it's already `byte[]`, if not you can convert it.

And

```
 Convert.ToByte(row[pro.Name])
```

is definitely not what you want.  It converts a value to a single `byte` not a `byte[]`.