# Datastage : Convert Binary to Base64

Tags: binary, base64, datastage

I need to convert a binary column from sql server db to base64 column and load it into a oracle db.
How can we do this in datastage or SQL query.

Comment: If you show what you have tried, you might get more answers. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664937/retrieve-varbinary-value-as-base64-in-mssql